# The Odd/Even Extensions and Why We even do Them?

Tags: fourier-series, even-and-odd-functions

I have the following problem. Let
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
x & 0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, \\
x-\pi &  \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \pi
\end{cases}
$$
and let $h$ be the odd extension of $f$ to $[-, ]$. Find the Fourier series of $h$ on $[-,]$.

So I defined $h$ as
$$
h(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
x+\pi &  -\pi\leq x \leq \frac{-\pi}{2}, \\
x & \frac{-\pi}{2} \leq x \leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Now, it's an odd extension so $a_n$ is $0$ and $b_n$ is
$$b_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{-\pi/2} x\sin(nx)\, \mathrm dx + \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{0} x\sin(nx) \, \mathrm dx + 2\int_{-\pi}^{-\pi/2} \sin(nx) \, \mathrm dx.$$

Now I got this answer: $$b_n = \frac{-2\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{n}$$ which is wrong as it should be $$b_n = \frac{4}{n^2\pi}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right).$$

My question is: (1) how did they get that answer and (2) why do we even bother to do odd extension when we can say "oh, I did an odd expansion... The function is even now..."?

Comment: But why "The function is even now...", when the function $h$ is odd?

Comment: @peterwhy the function h is odd and sin(nx) is odd, which makes it an even integral?

Comment: I see, so your "The function" means $h(x)\sin(nx)$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer $$b_n = \frac{4}{n^2\pi}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$ is for a different problem, namely
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
x & 0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, \\
\pi-x &  \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \pi ,
\end{cases}
$$
a continuous sawtooth graph.  Unlike this one, your function is discontinuous at $x=\pi/2$.

[A Fourier series with coefficients going to zero as fast as $1/n^2$ converges uniformly, so it must yield a continuous function.]

Comment: I calculated the Fourier series for the function you suggested and I get the same answer as in my question!? I really dont see how we can get a sine-term!